# Fan on Acer Aspire 5315 not working

Tags: 12.04, acer, fancontrol

I have recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my old laptop (Acer Aspire 5315 ) and observed that fan is not working properly on Ubuntu.
How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

**Issue:**

What the problem is that its a problem with the version of Bios your using,its a bug which prevents your CPU fan from working and causes your PC to overheat so then your Motherboard shuts the PC down to prevent damage.

**Solution:**

The solution is to download the latest Bios Version for your Acer Aspire 5315, theirs only a windows installer for this on the Acer website,Link for Windows Bios

- Update:http://support.acer.com/us/en/product/default.aspx?tab=1&modelId=50.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known design problem with the Acer Aspire 5315 preventing the fan to work properly and eventually shutting down the computer to protect from overheating.

Solution comes from [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=4651436&postcount=99) and [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/acpi-bugzilla@lists.sourceforge.net/msg14582.html). You will have to register an account in order to download the fix.

You'll have to install `mempat binary` and `acer_fancontrol script` into `/usr/bin`.

You have to find out the correct memory address for `mmap()`.

For the 5315 wit 1.5G RAM PATCH_ADDRESS=x5F6BCEAF.

Add acer_fancontrol to /etc/rc.local and restart.

Source: http://www.fugaz.net/2010/01/23/acer-aspire-fan-issue-solved/

In other cases, a simple bios upgrade worked: http://support.acer-euro.com/drivers/notebook/as_5315.html

Answer (score 0):

simply update the BIOS of laptop by downloading it from acer support center .

Answer (score 0):

I have an Acer Aspire 5750g that's fan wasn't working (at all, whether in Windows, booting up, etc.).

I took off the keyboard (you don't have to take it off all the way) and poked it a bit, and it turned out the fan was jammed up, and by poking it, I was able to un-jam it.

This would only apply to people whose fan never works, not even on startup.